# Как в WPF создать MessageBox, при выборе YES - вып. действ1, NO - действ2?

Tags: c#, wpf

Как в WPF создать MessageBox, при выборе YES - вып. действ1, NO - действ2?

Мне выдается окно, я могу кликнуть ДА или НЕТ, при выборе ДА исполняется код, При выборе НЕТ также исполняется код, кнопка EXIT в правом верхнем угле MessageBox должна быть недоступна.

Мой неработающий код:

```
            string message = "Открыть Ворота?";
            string caption = "Ворота";
            MessageBoxButton buttons = MessageBoxButton.YesNo;
            string result;

            // Displays the MessageBox.

            result = MessageBox.Show(message, caption, buttons,
            MessageBoxImage.Question);

            if (result == "IDNO")
            {

                // Closes the parent form.

                this.Close();

            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MessageBox.Show возвращает не строку а MessageBoxResult поэтому проверяем так:

```
if (result == MessageBoxResult.Yes) {}
```

Кнопки EXIT в правом верхнем углу при MessageBoxButton.YesNo у вас и так не будет